How can I activate an animation for a newly rendered view in SwiftUI without using a timer or DispatchQueue?
I have a newly rendered view that appears conditionally. In one condition, the view truly does not exist (it’s not simply hidden with opacity), and in the other condition, it does, as shown in the code below. My goal is to toggle an animation value without using a timer or DispatchQueue. I currently have to rely on DispatchQueue or a timer in such cases, and I’m wondering if there’s a way to activate animations for freshly rendered views without using timers or DispatchQueue.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showView: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            if (showView) {
                TextView()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Show View") {
                showView.toggle()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}




struct TextView: View {
    
    @State private var rotationAnimation: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .bold()
            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotationAnimation ? 360 : .zero))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: rotationAnimation)
            .onAppear {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    rotationAnimation.toggle()
                }
                
            }
        
    }
}


You want to start the animation as soon as the view appears and not wait for 0.1 seconds, right? Just remove the DispatchQueue then. Does the animation not work? It does work for me on iOS 18.0 simulator.

Yes, that is right, I tried my code on macOS, it does not work just with onAppear I have to give some time like 0.1 sec

I just tried on macOS 15.0 and cannot reproduce, so probably just a SwiftUI bug.

I think so, I am using lower version than yours, I cannot risk to update.

You can’t use DispatchQueue in View structs that have no lifetime. You need to either use .task or the old @StateObject.

I made this way, it works for me, without using timer or DispatchQueue.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showView: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            
            if (showView) {
                TextView()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button("Show View") {
                showView.toggle()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}


struct TextView: View {
    
    @State private var rotationAnimation: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .bold()
            .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotationAnimation ? 360 : .zero))
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: rotationAnimation)
            .onAppearAnimation(action: {
                rotationAnimation.toggle()
            })
        
    }
}

struct OnAppearAnimationView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let action: () -> Void
    let content: () -> Content

    @State private var viewDidAppear: Bool = Bool()
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.action = action
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        content()
            .onAppear {
                viewDidAppear.toggle()
            }
            .onChange(of: viewDidAppear) { (oldValue, newValue) in
                if (oldValue != newValue) && (newValue) {
                    action()
                }
            }

    }
    
}

extension View {
    
    func onAppearAnimation(action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        return OnAppearAnimationView(action: action, content: { self })
    }
    
}


It's best to do self.content = content() https://onmyway133.com/posts/wwdc-swiftui-lounge/#use-viewbuillder

onChange has an initial: bool param which means onAppear
